# Travelling to Schengen with Romania Temporary Residence Permit

Tags: visas, schengen, romania, azerbaijani-citizens

I'm from Azerbaijan. I will continue my education in Romania for a semester. So, Can i go to Schengen countries with  Romania Temporary Residence Permit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Romania residence permit doesn't grant any permission to enter the Schengen area without a visa (unless it is for a family member of an EU citizen, but this is not the type of residence permit you have). You will need to obtain a regular short stay Schengen visa if you wish to travel to the Schengen area.